# Count characters in two p's and trim in the second p if more than 290 characters?

Tags: jquery, count

I'm rendering questions on a page with a title and content, and if the total number of characters (in both title and content) exceed 290 characters I want to trim the last x characters in the content div so that the total number of characters will be 290. I also want to add "..." in the end.

With the code below I check the total number of characters (*count*) but I can't come up with a solution for the rest. I guess I could use *substr()*?

```
<div class="question_list">
    <div class="itemtext">
        <p>This is a title</p>
        <p>This is some content.</p>
    </div
</div>
<div class="question_list">
    <div class="itemtext">
        <p>This is another title</p>
        <p>This is the content in the other question.</p>
    </div>
</div>


$('.question_list').find('.itemtext').each(function(){
    var count = $(this).find("p").text().length;
    while (count >= 290) {
        // ?
    }
});
```

Comment: If it's a certain width / height rather than an absolute character count you want, you can do this with CSS and `text-overflow: ellipsis;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it as follows:

```
$('.question_list').find('.itemtext').each(function(){
    var count = $(this).find("p").text().length;
    if (count < 290) {
        return;
    }
    var remaining = 290 - $(this).find("p").first().text().length;
    var oldText = $(this).find("p").last().text();
    $(this).find("p").last().text(oldText.substr(0, remaining) + '...');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wdfMy/

Comment: Note that I did it for 250 chars on the fiddle, not 290.

Comment: You may also want to bear in mind that this will fire on 290 characters exactly, and then add three more characters (the '...'), so you might want to check for `count < 293`.